# comment package and macro .sty file causing problems, why?

Tags: macros, errors, packages

Here's `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[]{myprob}{Problem}%
{colframe=blue!35!black,enlarge top by=0.15cm,fonttitle=\slshape,breakable}{prob}


\includecomment{analysis}
\includecomment{solution}

\usepackage{ana}

\title{Testing Doc}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{analysis}
\section{Analysis}
\subsection{Basic Integration}
\csname ANAsp2015p1\endcsname
\end{analysis}

\end{document}
```

and `ana.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{ana}[2021/08/11 Analysis Problems]

\expandafter\newcommand\csname ANAsp2015p1\endcsname{
\begin{myprob}{Spring 2015 Problem 1}{}
blah
\end{myprob}

\begin{solution}
Proof:
\end{solution}
}
```

Overleaf tells me "! File ended while scanning use of \next", and "I suspect you have forgotten a '}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop". If I delete the `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}` stuff from `ana.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{ana}[2021/08/11 Analysis Problems]

\expandafter\newcommand\csname ANAsp2015p1\endcsname{
\begin{myprob}{Spring 2015 Problem 1}{}
blah
\end{myprob}
}
```

the code runs fine. Originally I thought it had something to do with me nesting the comment environment `\begin{solution}...\end{solution}` inside another comment environment `\begin{analysis}...\end{analysis}`, but the error remained after I got rid of `\begin{analysis}` and `\end{analysis}`. Does anyone know what's going on?

I have looked at [comment-package and macro definitions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332057/comment-package-and-macro-definitions) but no one explained why this error happens.

Comment: I believe it's a `\catcode` issue. By wrapping the `solution` environment in a macro, `\catcode`s are frozen, while `comment` relies on `\catcode` changes to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) pointed out in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610362/comment-package-and-macro-sty-file-causing-problems-why#comment1526789_610362), it is a catcode-issue:

Iirc the environment `solution` expects to detect its end by finding tokens coming from tokenizing the phrase `\end{solution}` under verbatim-catcode-régime.  In your scenario, however, that phrase is not tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime but it got tokenized under usual catcode-régime already at the time of tokenizing the definition of `\ANAsp2015p1`.

You can circumvent that issue by having the tokens that shall form the definition of `\ANAsp2015p1` read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime and defining `\ANAsp2015p1` to pass these tokens to `\scantokens` for retokenization.

The following example provides a command `\DefineProbSolCmd` which does these things. Like `\verb` or `verbatim`-environment etc, the command `\DefineProbSolCmd` can only be used in situations where it obtains its argument directly by reading and tokenizing from a  .tex-input-file. The command `\DefineProbSolCmd` cannot be used as component of a macro-argument or of a definition-text of a macro or of the content of a token-register, etc.

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{ana}[2021/08/12 Analysis Problems]
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand\DefineProbSolCmd{}{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12\relax % Give "horizontal tab" catcode 12. See comment below for the reason.
  \InnerDefineProbSolCmd
}%
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^A=14
\catcode`\%=12
\@firstofone{^^A
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\InnerDefineProbSolCmd{m+v}{^^A
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar\scantokens{\endgroup#2%}}^^A
  }^^A
}%
% Reason for changing the catcode of horizontal tab:
% xparse's processor of v/+v-arguments leaves the catcode of
% "horizontal tab" at 10(space) so that tokenizing horizontal tabs
% yields space-tokens, which is undesired at this stage of
% processing.
%
\DefineProbSolCmd{ANAsp2015p1}{%
\begin{myprob}{Spring 2015 Problem 1}{}
blah
\end{myprob}

\begin{solution}
Proof:
\end{solution}
}%
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}


\newtcbtheorem[]{myprob}{Problem}%
{colframe=blue!35!black,enlarge top by=0.15cm,fonttitle=\slshape,breakable}{prob}


\includecomment{analysis}
\includecomment{solution}

\usepackage{ana}

\title{Testing Doc}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{analysis}
\section{Analysis}
\subsection{Basic Integration}
\csname ANAsp2015p1\endcsname
\end{analysis}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*An environment "solution" is in use. If I had to give assignments in a class, I would never make a pretty sheet with the solutions. To minimize the chance of it getting into the hands of course participants and circulating. When discussing solutions, I prefer blackboard writing, if only because writing on the board regulates the speed at which information is conveyed so that it is better absorbed.*

Comment: +1 Help my memory, what's `^^A` again?

Comment: @campa `^^A` is `^^`-notation for the character whose code-point in TeX's internal character-representation-scheme has the number <code-point-number of A> - 64 = 1. Such number is also called "character code". TeX's internal character-representation-scheme in turn with traditional TeX-engines is ASCII and with LuaTeX and XeTeX is unicode whereof ASCII is a strict subset. So `^^A` denotes the character whose code-point-number in ASCII has the value "1", i.e., the SOH-character=start of heading character. It is not a printable character. In my example it is temporarily used as comment-character.

Comment: @campa I use it temporarily as comment-char so that the usual comment-character `%` can be assigned catcode 12. That in turn is necessary to get it at the end of the <balanced text> of the `\scantokens`-directive. Otherwise the endline-character inserted by `\scantokens` when doing the reading-back-part and encountering the end of the "line" might get processed, yielding a space-token and thus undesired horizontal glue in some situations.